# Can I put a one minute delay on my hose so I don't get wet when the sprinkler turns on?

Tags: watering, tools, hoses

All I want is a water timer with about a 1-minute delay for those times that I have to run away after starting it and still get wet.  Like when I'm ready to go to work and don't want those clothes to get wet.

Answer (score 3):

Put a valve at your hydrant, so that you can turn on the hose/sprinkler  after walking back to your source. It's the easiest way if you aren't looking for a permanent sprinkler system install.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sheila, this is very sweet.  There are timers that you can set on your hose to go off when you are high and dry in your car.  No delay is necessary other than the start time is after you are in your car.  Most timers are built like that.  I would purchase a GOOD timer...like more expensive than the cheapest?  What plants are you watering and for how long?  How do you know how much time to set your sprinklers for?  We could help with that.  In fact we could help you train your lawn and plants to be drought tolerant and save huge bucks on your water bill. Watering a little every day is not at all a good thing.  Tell us more about your situation, send pictures. Wouldn't you be proud to come home to a thriving landscape surrounding your home?  Lower your water bills?